# p:selectOneMenu default appearance

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I put next to each other an p:inputText and p:selectOneMenu item.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Tester</title>
    </h:head>    
    <h:body> 
        <h:form>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:inputText value="#{myBean.text}" />        
                <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{myBean.combo}">        
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Red" itemValue="R" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="G" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="B" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>        
            </p:panelGrid>

        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I can a problem with the default appearance of p:selectOneMenu. Bottom of texts in inputtext selectOneMenu are not aligned, and on the right button slipped. I did not set any style.

[image]

I tried to solve it with setting the style various way (height of .ui-selectonemenu-label and .ui-selectonemenu) but there was no success.
I do not necessarily expect the default appearance to be good, but if this does not happen to others, then probably something in my environment can be a wrong.

Primefaces 6.1.4, Firefox 55.0.3

Comment: what if you don't use a panelgrid but display them directly next to each other?

Comment: <h:form>            
                <p:inputText value="#{myBean.text}" />        
                <p:selectOneMenu id="console" value="#{myBean.combo}">        
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Red" itemValue="R" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Green" itemValue="G" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Blue" itemValue="B" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>        
        </h:form>

Comment: I found no difference.